# a Query contains MAX() and MIN() with their own conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

In my query here

```
$Query = "SELECT id, name FROM names WHERE age = 18 LIMIT 1";
```

I want to add `MIN()` and `MAX()` with a condition as if i made another query like this

`$MQuery = "SELECT MAX/MIN(age) FROM names LIMIT 1";`

My solution was merging the three queries together like this

```
$Query = "SELECT id, name, 
(SELECT MAX(age) FROM names WHERE  age = 18 AND age > 18 LIMIT 1) as MAX, 
(SELECT MIN(age) FROM names WHERE  age = 18 AND age < 18 LIMIT 1) as MIN
FROM names WHERE age = 18 LIMIT 1";
```

But i wonder if there is a more efficient way and quicker to write it, Like

```
$Query = "SELECT id, name, 
(MAX(age) WHERE age > 18) as MAX, 
(MIN(age) WHERE age < 18) as MIN 
FROM names WHERE age = 18 LIMIT 1";
```

also, Is there any idea of using `LIMIT 1` or `DISTINCT` with `MAX/MIN()`-only queries?

What i expect is that if there is age `19` or age `17` to catch it using `MIN` and `MAX` if they exist

```
[id - name - max -min
[1 - Mario - 19 - 17]
```

table would be like

```
[id - name - age]
[1  - mario - 18]
[2  - arizo - 18]
[3  - bruno - 17]
[4  - arizo - 19]
[5  - mario - 18]
```

Comment: What are you trying to get done? What is the required output?

Comment: @Vashi I want to get the next/previous `age` if they exist. will add an example now

Comment: Next/previous age w.r.t. 18 ?

Comment: @Vashi yes, So i get the `id` and `name` for `18` but only the `MIN` for `< 18` and `MAX for > 18`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MAX(CASE WHEN..)` could be your way out. Also I changed the equality signs(if the age is greater than 18, you want the minimum of age in [19 to whatever] and for ages less than 18, you want max of age in [1 to 17]. Also I don't see the need for `LIMIT 1`.

```
SELECT id, name, 
MAX(CASE WHEN age<18 THEN age END) as Max_age,
MIN(CASE WHEN age>18 THEN age END) as Min_age
FROM names
GROUP BY id, name;
```

Note: The next/previous age w.r.t. 18 will only apply to a given `id` in consideration i.e. if that particular `id` has more than one entry with different ages.

Comment: I have to use `LIMIT 1` because of some duplicated entries, I've tried it with and without `LIMIT 1` but didn't get any values, Is it because i have `WHERE age = 18`?

Comment: Can you add some sample entries for some `id`?

Comment: And Yes, `WHERE age = 18` does not seem to be required(I didn't use it in my post). Did you try without the WHERE condition?

Comment: Yes, Tried and worked without `WHERE age = 18`, But the page needs it to define what age member to show

Comment: Didn't get you "page needs it to define ...". If you use `WHERE age = 18` then MAX and MIN both will give you NULL or some unknown value because it will first execute WHERE and then it will execute MAX/MIN where CASE WHEN will only look for entries with age more/less than 18.

Comment: I guess i got `Null` since the `print`ed value is nothing inside the html, Does it require using two in one query in this case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161943/discussion-between-vashi-and-toleo).